# Error in Editing Bot Token

Tags: botframework, telegram-bot

I have registered a bot in botframework. When I click on the edit button (the following figure)

[image]

to resubmit the token of the bot (the following figure)

[image]

I face with the following error:

[image]

Is there any suggestion to solve this? Does this come from the Microsoft's servers?

Comment: Apparently, it was a temporary problem.